# About strange behavior when giving bounties

Tags: support, flagging

Searching around the unanswered questions I saw this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1671427/133781) which hadn't had any answers before and now I found that it recently has three answers, and I suppose that this happen because some user offered a bounty on this question.

My concern is that the user who offer the bounty gave it to a very poor written and definitely wrong [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2078162/133781), which I even downvoted because as I said  it's totally wrong, but even more curious is the fact that 5 users upvoted that answer (?). I think this isn't a good behavior. I mean what's the point to offer a bounty if you give it to someone who wrote an incorrect answer!

So my question is, what should I do if I see things like this? Should I call the moderators?  Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I think if you care that someone is "spending" their reputation recklessly (by awarding bounties to poor answers), you should comment, to make this user aware of your issues with the answer, in addition to downvoting. I do find it really strange though for the answer to have gotten so many upvotes though; it *really* doesn't look like a solution to a divisibility question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general it is not a moderators' activity to [decide on correctness of answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2473/is-it-in-the-moderators-job-description-to-patrol-for-correctness).

It can and does happen that incorrect or otherwise lacking answers are evaluated positively by some users in good faith out of ignorance. This is of course not optimal but can happen and there is nothing for a moderator to do.

If you notice this, it can make sense to leave a comment pointing out, in a constructive and tactful way, shortcomings of the answer and if possible ways to improve or to clarify it. Downvoting in addition or instead of a comment is also an option (although downvotes without explanation are less meaningful as feedback).

However, if you should believe that votes or a bounty were not given in good faith and there might be something dubious going on, then indeed you could flag for moderators: flag, "other" and explain your concern.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Good advice! Flagging is what you should do, when you spot something like this. Moderators can then investigate and ask for help from the SE staff if they find something that warrants escalating the matter. I was shaking my head at that bounty well before attention was drawn to it in this meta thread. Let's see if a clear picture emerges: [This meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/25525/11619) may be interesting. The only other answer competing for the bounty, posted after that meta post, received 3 LQ flags from users within a small geographical area.

Comment: (cont'd)  That competing answer also received 5 downvotes. Then the "winning" answer was posted by another user possibly from the same small area. And promptly earned 5 upvotes.