# If not flagging, how to dispute incorrect answers?

Tags: support, answers, flagging

I was browsing the top [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series) questions for fun and stumbled upon [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1164035), where the only answer is incorrect (the user misconstrued the problem and tiled $[0,1]^2$ with rectangles of the right area but wrong sides). In the past I have flagged such answers as 'not an answer' under the interpretation that answers must be correct, but the flags are often disputed. So I flagged this answer as 'in need of moderator intervention' and explained the reason the post was incorrect and should be deleted. The response was 'declined- flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer'.

So, if we can't flag incorrect posts as Not An Answer or use them to bring to moderator attention, what recourse do we have to remove false answers, especially from old questions? On older posts sometimes there isn't an option to flag as 'very low quality,' which compounds the issue.

Comment: The original post is now deleted but I think my question and Glorfindel's answer are still useful, so I'll leave this up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, you can do the following:

- Downvote the answer
- If not already present, leave a comment indicating why the answer is incorrect (possibly with ways to improve it)
- If possible, post another answer which is correct

Flagging is not the right option since it's not the moderators' job to determine whether an answer is correct or not.

Relevant posts on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [What is the accepted practice with incorrect answer that have been upvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158574/295232)
- [Should I nominate incorrect answers for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143576/295232)
- [What is the rationale behind only downvoting incorrect answers instead of voting to delete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163900/295232)
- [How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/295232)

Comment: Also on this meta: [Is it in the Moderator's Job Description to patrol for correctness?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2473) (Maybe also [Don't flag wrong answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4731) and [some other questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2473).)

Comment: Is this something that the CURED chat room could handle? (I've never participated in CURED but I've seen it discussed here on meta.se.)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC You are welcome to bring such an incorrect answer to the attention of CURED-regulars. Anyone capable of spotting the error should still write that comment (and/or downvote an/or post a correct answer). Posting a link to the erroneous answer in CURED is a nice follow up, and likely to lead others joining in the action. But, there's no need to outsource the "dirty work" to CURED alone - community moderation is kind of a civic duty.

Comment: Glad you commented, @JyrkiLahtonen.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - Thanks. I don't actually have such an issue myself; just curious if this might be another resource for the OP. And good point about all pulling together.