# Should I flag an answer if the answer is wrong?

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging

I am referring to this flag I raised-
[image]

[The answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191572/prove-that-ii-is-a-real-number/3809194#3809194) should have been deleted, apart from being downvoted. For this purpose, couldn't I flag? These types of answers (from high rep. users) lower the quality of MSE.

Edit: The answer is now deleted.

Comment: You might check: [Don't flag wrong answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4731) (and [other questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4731), [Is it in the Moderator's Job Description to patrol for correctness?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2473) (and [other questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2473)). (This one is related not specifically to flagging but the removal of wrong answers: [Should we vote to delete wrong answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27423))

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Are blatantly wrong answers very low quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality)

Comment: You can bring up wrong answers and misleading answers and non-answers in [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured) where there are people with expertise from various fields who can typically act more appropriately than review queues (it seems that low-quality and non-answer reviews regularly get botched even in the most blatantly unambiguous cases).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you should flag low quality content. But you should use the standard flags, i.e. "Very low quality" and "Not an answer" (when applicable) or "This question should be closed" (when applicable).

These flags will push the post into the review queues where they can be reviewed by users and acted upon.

You, in this case, used a free-form flag to notify *the moderators* of a low quality post. Don't do that. We are not referees of mathematical content. We try to avoid exercising our powers when unnecessary since our votes are binding, and in the case of deletion irreversible by normal users. This is why your flag was rejected. We have enough work on our hands with content that we *should* deal with, and flagging bad content for *moderator attention* will simply get your flag rejected.

Comment: Thanks for posting this now! And thanks to @MartinSleziak  for the references too! It hits me because few days ago I flagged [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/792680/316749) , accompanied by the comment
"This answer is plainly wrong, and I'm pleading to get it deleted."
The flag was rejected which is in line with this thread.
How/where can I vote for deletion of an answer? Is there a corresponding rep threshold which I haven't reached?

Comment: @Hanno, as Asaf says, you can flag as "very low quality" or as "not an answer" if one of those flags is applicable. You can also leave a comment pointing out what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, that worked. After flagging as "Not an A" it is deleted by now.

Comment: Also, [wrong answers are not very low quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality) - that's what downvotes are for.

Answer (score 2):

Related on MSO: [Are blatantly wrong answers very low quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality) Short answer: wrong answers are not very low quality. That's what downvotes are for.

Wrong answers are actually beneficial to the site if they're downvoted (ideally with comments explaining why they're wrong) - that way they can serve as a warning to others against making a similar mistake. In the specific case you cite, the answer was already downvoted, so there's no point in deleting it - the downvotes should already serve as a warning there's some problem with the answer. You could add a fifth downvote or add a comment explaining what the problem is, both of which would be useful.

Also, please don't use custom flags for stuff that the community can take care of. If you think that a question is very low quality or not an answer, use a standard flag so that the community can take care of it without having to bother the moderators about it.